# Display List of Uploaded files antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working on a project where I am using antd 4 there I am having an issue with antd Upload list.

Basically, I have an user who has uploaded the documents and now when the user is trying to editing the files which he has uploaded are not showing up. The data is coming from cookie entire form has been populated except upload component.

here is the code of the same.

```
<Form
            layout="vertical"
            className="user-forms"
            name="editprofile"
            initialValues={{
              remember: true,
              id: user.id,
              firstname: user.first_name,
              lastname: user.last_name,
              uploadotherdoc: user.userDocuments
                ? user.userDocuments.map(item => ({
                  ...item,
                  uid: Math.random(),
                }))
                : null,
            }}
            colon={false}
            onFinish={values => onFinish(values, editAgentDetailsData)}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
          >
          <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col xs={24} lg={8}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="firstname"
                  label={formatMessage({
                    id: 'component.form.firstname',
                  })}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: `Please Enter the ${formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.firstname',
                      })}`,
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    defaultValue="Emile"
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    placeholder={formatMessage({
                      id: 'component.form.firstname',
                    })}
                    size="large"
                    className="pickerwidth"
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={24} lg={8}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="lastname"
                  label={formatMessage({
                    id: 'component.form.lastname',
                  })}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: `Please Enter the ${formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.lastname',
                      })}`,
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    defaultValue="Pettersen"
                    placeholder={formatMessage({
                      id: 'component.form.lastname',
                    })}
                    size="large"
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col xs={24} lg={8}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="email"
                  label={formatMessage({
                    id: 'component.form.email',
                  })}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: `Please Enter the ${formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.email',
                      })}`,
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    disabled
                    defaultValue="emilieP12@webmegling.no"
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    placeholder={formatMessage({
                      id: 'component.form.email',
                    })}
                    size="large"
                    className="pickerwidth"
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={24} lg={8}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="phone"
                  label={formatMessage({
                    id: 'component.form.phone',
                  })}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: `Please Enter the ${formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.phone',
                      })}`,
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input
                    // disabled
                    placeholder={formatMessage({
                      id: 'component.form.phone',
                    })}
                    size="large"
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          <Row gutter={8}>
              <Col xs={24} lg={16}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="uploadotherdoc"
                  label={formatMessage({
                    id: 'component.form.uploadotherdoc',
                  })}
                  valuePropName="fileList"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: `Please Enter the ${formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.uploadotherdoc',
                      })}`,
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Upload
                    accept=".pdf"
                    defaultFileList={user.userDocuments.map(item => ({
                      ...item,
                      uid: Math.random(),
                    }))}
                    {...docprops}
                    action={onactionChange}
                    onChange={onUploadDocChange}
                  >
                    <Button className="borderradius">
                      <UploadOutlined />
                      {formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.uploadotherdoc',
                      })}
                    </Button>
                  </Upload>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="mt-3">
              <Col xs={24}>
                <div className="flex-container">
                  <div>
                    <Button
                      type="primary"
                      htmlType="submit"
                      className="primary buttons admin-forms-btn"
                      size="large"
                    >
                      {formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.update',
                      })}
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      className="text-primary admin-forms-btn cancel-btn"
                      style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}
                      size="large"
                      onClick={router.goBack}
                    >
                      {formatMessage({
                        id: 'component.form.cancel',
                      })}
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
```

I have tried quite a few things but none worked. I will be grateful if anyone can able to figure this out. this is the minimal demo.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what is going wrong, since your example hides a lot of the implementation details, but here is a working minimal CodeSandbox demo of what you are trying to accomplish.

[CodeSandbox: Form Upload Preview Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-upload-preview-tjigt?file=/src/App.js)

A few notes: It seems redundant to set both a `defaultFileList` value directly on the `Upload` component and to set a default value for `uploadotherdoc` via `initialValues` on the `Form` component. I believe the correct use case is to set the default value through `initialValues` on the `Form`.

It also seems strange that you are directly controlling the behavior of `Upload` component via the `onChange` handler, since that functionality is handled by the `Form` component via the `getValueFromEvent` handler on the `Form.Item` that wraps the `Upload` component. See demo for details.

One final thing, it's probably not a good idea to set `uid` to a random value. It should be unique and stable, since it's used as a React `key` prop for the uploaded preview list.